# Container 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My header is on the top fixed.

My footer is fixed on the bottem.

And there is nothing to scroll.

How is it posible that the #content is 100% high of the left space in the middle?

```css
body{overflow-y:hidden;}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

header{
    background-color:yellow;
}

section#content{
    background-color:green;
    height:100%
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header
</header>
<section id="content">
    Content
</section>
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Where's the `css`?

Comment: When you use `display:fixed`, the `element` will be removed from the flow of the document, meaning it's like the parent has no child, thus the `height:100%` will not work

Comment: share the CSS also. so we can help.

Comment: sorry I forgot the css. I have edit it.

Comment: The answer is that the section is **NOT** 100% high. Its parent, the body, doesn't have a height specified, so the height property of the section is ignored and it is just as high as its content (one line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that the `html` and the `body` wasn't the 100% of the height, as also [said correctly in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887256/container-100-height/43887590#comment74809152_43887256).

Adding `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` will make it work

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

section#content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<section id="content">
  Content
</section>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you, when I give the footer a backgournd-color it is working.

Comment: You are welcome, I also added some `background-color` to the `footer` to make more comprehensive where is the `header`,`selection` and `footer`.

Answer (score 0):

> i think you want like this. check snippet

```js
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var headHeight = $('header').height();
var footHeight = $('header').height();
 var headFoot =headHeight+footHeight

$("#content").css("height",winHeight -headFoot);
```

```css
body{overflow-y:hidden; margin:0px;}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background:red;
}

header{
    background-color:yellow;
     width: 100%;
}

section#content{
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    Header
</header>
<section id="content">
    Content
</section>
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: No need for the JS but if you were you use it, you might want to add a listener for if the page resizes